# Why does the cell not revert back to ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the Macro that I wrote. What I want is for the cell to pull in the results from the tab titled Results cell B3. When I run the macro, everything works except for when I override the value in cell B3 it doesn't revert back to the =Results!B3 like I want it to when I make a change to the C9 cell.

[image]

Comment: Worksheet_Change events should be in the worksheet code to which it runs, not a module.

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) always include the code in your question and format it as code block.